# When Spring Boot is serving a NextJS static export, can I make it show the NextJS 404 page?

Tags: spring-boot, next.js

I have a barebones Spring Boot app, with a NextJS app under `src/main/react`. I'm using the frontend-maven-plugin to build it, and then maven-resources-plugin to copy the output to `resources/static`.

Currently, for paths that don't exist, I get the Spring Whitelabel Error page. It mentions:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error
```

I could create a custom page for `/error`, and this works. Although, it doesn't inherit the rest of the app's CSS. This behaviour also doesn't line up with using the app in development.

Ideally, I would like to just use the `404.html` that Next generates for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine Next.js SSG with a Spring Boot server, the application serves the index.html file from the resources/static directory, which is generated by Next.js. Initially, this allows your application to function as intended. However, when you attempt to refresh the page or manually enter a URL in the browser, you may encounter a 404 error. This happens because there is no routing configuration in the Spring application to handle these requests. This issue arises because the Spring backend was designed exclusively for API functionality.

To resolve this issue, you can divide the solution into two parts, one for the frontend and one for the backend.

**Frontend Part:**

In your Next.js app, create a page named PageRefresh.js with the following content:

```
function PageRefresh() {
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
        router.push(router.asPath).catch((e) => {
            router.push('/_error');
        });
    }
}, [router.isReady])
return (
    <div>Loading...</div>
);
export default PageRefresh;
```

**Backend Part:**

In your Spring Boot application, create a component named PageRefreshFilter.java as follows:

```
@Component
public class PageRefreshFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String PAGE = "/pagerefresh/pagerefresh.html";
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        doFilter((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response, chain);
    }
    private void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        if ("/".equals(path) || path.contains(".") || path.contains("e3docs")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(PAGE).forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

This backend filter ensures that any request coming to the server will be forwarded to the UI router, except for API or data files(like CSS, JS, etc.). This approach should address the issue of 404 errors when refreshing or entering URLs manually in the browser while using Next.js SSG with a Spring Boot backend, for more refer to this https://www.e3docs.com/blog/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-spring-boot-and-next-js/